# Colored circle with arrow around section of equation

Tags: equations, tikz-arrows

I wanted to know if it is possible to have a more compact circled block like this:[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\hat{x}^{-}_{k+1} & = \tikz[baseline]{ \node[draw=red,fill=red!20,anchor=base,circle,inner sep = 0pt]
  (d1) {$e^{-1}\hat{x}_{k}$}}\vspace{3cm}\nonumber\\
\hat{x}_{k+1} & = \hat{x}^{-}_{k+1} + K_{k+1}(z_{k+1}-e^{-1}\hat{x}_{k})\nonumber
\end{align}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red,thick,->] (d1) to [in=90,out=235] +(270:1cm) node[anchor=north,text = black,] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The existing circle (in red) is too large and makes the equation look awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

It is easy, just replace shape `circle` with `ellipse`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% just for showing only equation
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{preview}% <----
\begin{align}
\hat{x}^{-}_{k+1} & = \tikz[baseline]{\node[draw=red,fill=red!20,anchor=base,
                                            ellipse,inner xsep=-1pt,inner ysep=0pt]
                                        (d1) {$e^{-1}\hat{x}_{k}$}}
                        \notag   \\[1em]
\hat{x}_{k+1} & = \hat{x}^{-}_{k+1} + K_{k+1}(z_{k+1}-e^{-1}\hat{x}_{k})\nonumber
\end{align}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red,thick,->] (d1) to [in=90,out=225] +(255:8mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}% <---
    \end{document}
```

Edit: Now I litle clean-up of your MWE ...

Comment: Thank you.  As a side note, how do you increase the vertical space between the two equations?  I tried \vspace but that had no effect.  Thanks.

Comment: @Joe - You can do `\\[.4cm]` instead of only `\\...`.

Comment: @Joe, as said @AboAmmar in his comment, I use `\\[1em]` after end of the first equation line. See my edited code.